# How to create SQLContext in spark using scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, apache-spark-sql

I am creating a Scala program to `SQLContext` using sbt. This is my build.sbt:

```
name := "sampleScalaProject"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
//libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.11" % "0.8.2.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "1.5.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.6.0"
```

And this is test program:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

object SqlContextSparkScala {

  def main (args: Array[String]) {
    val sc = SparkContext
    val sqlcontext = new SQLContext(sc)
  }
}
```

I am getting below error:

```
Error:(8, 26) overloaded method constructor SQLContext with alternatives:
  (sparkContext: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext)org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext <and>
  (sparkContext: org.apache.spark.SparkContext)org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.SparkContext.type)
    val sqlcontexttest = new SQLContext(sc)
```

Can anybody please let me know the issue as I am very new to scala and spark programming?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `new` your `SparkContext` and that should solve it

Answer (score 12):

For **newer versions** of Spark (2.0+), use `SparkSession`:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

`SparkSession` can do everything `SQLContext` can do but if needed the `SQLContext` can be accessed as follows,

```
val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply we can create SQLContext in scala

```
scala> val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkJoins").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf);
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using scala shell then use below statement

```
val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
```

And to read parquet files use below statement

```
val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("/path/to/folder/cotaning/arquet/files/")
```